# Get IST date from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

When i query the database using sysdate i get the sysdate with PST timing. [ my server is in PST timezone)

How can i convert or get the IST date from PST. [ considering the daylight saving on/off ]

IST - Indian Standard Time. PST - Pacific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move to timestamp with timezone:

```
systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'IST'
```

PS: I have no oracle near for now and cannot check whether timezone with name "IST" exists or not. If not - you can find all the timezones in `SELECT tzname FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAME`

Comment: You can also use the UTC offset if Oracle doesn't have your timezone named:

systimestamp AT TIME ZONE '+05:30'

Comment: @Craig: yes, but in this case it will not be possible to handle summertime

Comment: good point..  if used in a script, that would have to be considered.  Another possibility would be to use "localtimestamp" instead of "systimestamp" if your session is already set with the correct time zone.